# Is "Misoneism" an actual word?

Tags: meaning

Cannot find word **misoneism** which I thought means hatred of change.  What is the 1)meaning  2) origin?

Comment: Uh, first Google result gives me [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misoneism).

Comment: [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=misoneism&ls=a) might be the best place to research a question like this one.

Answer (score 2):

It's in several dictionaries -- http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misoneism -- so I guess that makes it a real word.

Of course even if a word isn't in a standard dictionary doesn't necessarily make it not a real word. A word usually has to receive some level of general acceptance and recognition before it gets included in the dictionary. It's not like dictionary writers invent new words.